# Correctly convert string to UTF-8 via PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a file **test.HIO** its content this:

```
 11/08/2015 00:05:50»ЦО Ворота выход»Дверь не открыта»24001695»Бахром Суннатуллоевич Тургунов»99»»»
 11/08/2015 00:05:54»ЦО Ворота выход»Верный доступ»24001215»Шохрух Джохонгирович Исламов»99»»»
```

If i use linux command **file -i test.HIO** i get this info:

```
test.HI0: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

If i convert this file use php function **iconv** or **mb_convert_encoding**:

```
$file_content = file( "test.HIO" );

// for example i get one line from file
$str = iconv( "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $file_content[2] );
var_dump( $str );

$str2 = mb_convert_encoding( $file_content[2], "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1" );
var_dump( $str2 );
```

I get the same result:

```
 string(159) " 11/08/2015 00:05:45»ÖÎ Âîðîòà âûõîä»Âåðíûé äîñòóï»24001695»Áàõðîì Ñóííàòóëëîåâè÷ Òóðãóíîâ»99»»» "
```

If i just show file content in browser:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
$file_content = file( "test.HI0" );

echo $file_content[2];
```

i see this:

```
11/08/2015 00:07:17��� 2 ����������� �������24001066��������� ���������� �������99���
```

How correctly show or save text in UTF-8 encode? 
Thank in anvance.

UPD.

Thank to all. I find another solution it looks ugly, but working.

```
$file_content = file( "test.HIO" );

$str = iconv( "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $file_content[2] );

// OR

$str = mb_convert_encoding( $file_content[2], "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1" );

$str = iconv( 'utf-8', 'windows-1252', $str );
$str = iconv( 'windows-1251', 'utf-8', $str );

var_dump( $str );
```

UPD 2.

I chose the wrong way using **file -i** for detect file encoding.
As it turned out, my file encoding is **windows-1251**

```
chardet /home/file.HI0
/home/file.HI0: windows-1251 (confidence: 0.75)
```

or **@yangsunny** advice **enca**

```
enca -L ru /home/file.HI0
MS-Windows code page 1251
```

Eventually, can be used this code:

```
$file_content = file( "test.HIO" );

$str2 = mb_convert_encoding( $file_content[2], "UTF-8", "windows-1251" );
var_dump( $str2 );
```

Thank all for help.

Comment: Are you sure you have to convert this text into utf-8? I think it's already utf-8 text.

Comment: The encoding detection result you get ("iso-8859-1") is obviously wrong. There are no cyrillic characters in that char set. The issue here is that an automatic encoding detection simply is an impossible thing, especially for 8bit encodings. Neither is it reliable, nor does it deliver correct results. That simply is because it is impossible from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: Ok, why if i show text without encoding i see this 
11/08/2015 00:07:17��� 2 ����������� �������24001066��������� ���������� �������99���

Comment: IF the original data is really in `ISO-8859-1`, you can use `utf8_encode` to convert this to utf8.

Comment: you could try to use the php function `mb_detect_encoding()` with strict mode. Sadly, it doesnt always give the right result.

Comment: @yangsunny It never does. It's one of those functions that everybody uses by name but never really read the manual ;-)

Comment: @yangsunny, Alvaro Gonzalez, thank for help, but `mb_detect_encoding() ` return false when i use it.

Comment: maybe theres better way to "detect the right" encoding on linux? http://osmanov-dev-notes.blogspot.de/2010/07/how-to-handle-filename-encodings-in.html?showComment=1340093042160#c8103931008301575520

Comment: @yangsunny, thank, working. And i found an additional simple solution use `chardet` ubuntu command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing conversions the right way. The problem is that you don't know the source encoding. For example, think of currency conversion: you can convert £100 or ¥100 to US dollars. But you can't convert just "100".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (emphasis mine):

> ISO/IEC 8859-1:1998 [...] is generally intended for **Western European
>   languages** (see below for a list).

It's clear that Cyrillic text (Russian, Ukrainian or whatever) cannot be ISO-8859-1, an encoding that only has characters from the Latin alphabet.

Correct text encoding detection is a manual task. If you know for sure the text is Cyrillic, you need to do some research to find out what encodings support Cyrillic and then figure out which one better matches your data. You might need to get actual [hexadecimal values](http://php.net/bin2hex). Even then, there's still room for error. For instance, there might be encodings that are identical for 99% of characters but differ for the remaining 1%.